# VNC-Server as a virtual X11 monitor to expand screen

Tags: x11, vnc, xrandr, multi-monitor

From a currently running X11 session, I would like to provide/run a [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) server such that it appears to my system as a second, “virtual” monitor – i.e. so that I can position it using `xrandr` and drag/position windows onto it.

How, if at all, could I achieve that?

Edit: More info from OP in comments: "Also asked [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/libvncserver/mailman/message/27866988/), without an answer. "

Answer (score 16, accepted):

tl;dr: Force a "virtual" output of your graphics card to a display mode, and export that with [`x11vnc`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/x11vnc).

---

You can achieve this, but there are a few prerequisites:

- A graphics card with multi-head capabilities (= can render several "desktop" surfaces). Which is most cards these days.
- [`x11vnc`, a mature software](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) ([x11vnc](/questions/tagged/x11vnc)) to export X11 surfaces (among others) to [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) clients.

Most consumer cards these days can render several different outputs. Mine can do 3, out of the 5 that `xrandr` shows (eDP1,HDMI[12],DP[12]).

- Pick an unused output from [xrandr](/questions/tagged/xrandr), in my example `HDMI2`.
- Pick a resolution for the screen of the vnc client, and [generate a mode](ftp://www.x.org/pub/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/cvt.1.html):

  `$ cvt 1920 1080`
  `# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz`
  `Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync`
- Add that mode to `xrandr`

  `xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync`
- Put e.g. `HDMI2` in that mode, and attach to the right of `eDP1` (Main screen)

  `xrandr --addmode HDMI2 1920x1080_60 --output HDMI2 --mode 1920x1080_60 --right-of eDP1`
- Now export that with `x11vnc`, choosing the appropriate offset:

  `x11vnc -display :0 -clip 1920x1080+1600+0` `<other options>`

  Note: Add desired encryption/authentication/other options to that command.
- Now connect with a VNC client to your "virtual monitor". (or modify above command to connect to a "listening" VNC-client.

Comment: With the notebook screen and a VGA monitor it fails saying `xrandr: Configure crtc 2 failed`. If I use only one screen (either VGA or embedded one) it works. How can I make it work with both screens?

Answer (score 7):

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/391574/250606) to be able to use VIRTUAL1 instead of a real output like HDMI2, and be able to manage it (select resolution, arrange desktop geometry, clone or extend) in the desktop environment screen settings like any other physical monitor.