# Creating Virtual Monitors that I can turn on and off at will and that KDE can manage like any real external monitor

Tags: x11, virtual-machine, display, monitors

I'd like to create a Virtual Monitor that works like a real one. I'd like to be able to connect and disconnect it when I wish and to configure it using KDE System Settings: change its position/rotation, resolution etc.

My video card is AMD (I'm using the `amdgpu` video driver) and I'm running Arch Linux with the latest version of everything: amdgpu 19.1.0, linux 5.5.6, plasma 5.18.2 etc.

​

I found several similar posts on Unix&Linux and askubuntu, but none works:

- [VNC-Server as a virtual X11 monitor to expand screen problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/357959/vnc-server-as-a-virtual-x11-monitor-to-expand-screen-problem)

  Even if I create the configuration file and restart the X server, I get no Virtual monitors. X's log file says:

  ```
  Output eDP using monitor section Virtual Monitor
  ```
- [How do you use an android tablet as a second display?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28608/how-do-you-use-an-android-tablet-as-a-second-display)

  I have no VIRTUAL1 monitor and don't know how to create it.
- [VNC-Server as a virtual X11 monitor to expand screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156412/vnc-server-as-a-virtual-x11-monitor-to-expand-screen)

  If I use my existing output `DisplayPort-0` things seem to kind of work, but not quite...

  According to `xrandr`, `DisplayPort-0` never becomes `Connected`. `arandr` can see it and move it around, but KDE doesn't.

  Also, I don't know how to turn off that monitor (and then on again) after I enable it the first time.

  How can I force connect/disconnect and enable/disable `DisplayPort-0`, when I'm trying to use that output as a virtual one?

​

I'm creating a new post because none of the ones I found is quite exactly about this question and because the answers to those are old and no longer working.